# Part of Umbraco site Path disable css from site

Tags: css, umbraco

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I have an Umbraco site and except from this one error, it works perfect.

As normal in umbraco paths for sites look like

`Localhost:xxxxx/`
`Localhost:xxxxx/Blog/`
`Localhost:xxxxx/Blog/Blog-Item1/`

When I enter `Localhost:xxxxx/Blog/Blog-Item1/` ass css stops working / is removed, but if i remove the last `/` its back and working perfect.

`Localhost:xxxxx/Blog/Blog-Item1/` - NOT WORKING
`Localhost:xxxxx/Blog/Blog-Item1` - WORKING

Have anyone any idea why the last `/` makes my Css stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem once before, and I think it might be the same as you have.

Check you Links to your style sheets.

`<link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`- Not working
`<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` - Working

It kinda sure it will be the missing `~/` in your styles that is the problem.

Hope it works